# Estou realizando uma integração com o api da cielo porém recebo uma mensagem de erro:

Tags: java, api, web-service

Estou realizando uma integração com o api-cielo 3.0 porém estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro:

**codigo da aplicação**

```
package cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce;

import java.io.IOException;

import cieloecommerce.sdk.Merchant;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.Sale;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.Payment;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.CreditCard;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.CieloEcommerce;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.Environment;

import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.request.CieloError;
import cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.request.CieloRequestException;

public class Teste1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String MerchantID  = "123";
        String MerchantKey = "123";

        // Configure seu merchant
        Merchant merchant = new Merchant(MerchantID, MerchantKey);

        // Crie uma instância de Sale informando o ID do pagamento
        Sale sale = new Sale("123");

        // Crie uma instância de Customer informando o nome do cliente
        Customer customer = sale.customer("alex jose");

        // Crie uma instância de Payment informando o valor do pagamento
        Payment payment = sale.payment(1);

        // Crie  uma instância de Credit Card utilizando os dados de teste
        // esses dados estão disponíveis no manual de integração
        payment.creditCard("123", "MasterCard").setExpirationDate("11/2021")
                                         .setCardNumber("123123123")
                                         .setHolder("Fulano de Tal");

        // Crie o pagamento na Cielo
        try {
            // Configure o SDK com seu merchant e o ambiente apropriado para criar a venda
            sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).createSale(sale);

            // Com a venda criada na Cielo, já temos o ID do pagamento, TID e demais
            // dados retornados pela Cielo
            String paymentId = sale.getPayment().getPaymentId();

            // Com o ID do pagamento, podemos fazer sua captura, se ela não tiver sido capturada ainda
            sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).captureSale(paymentId, 15700, 0);

            // E também podemos fazer seu cancelamento, se for o caso
            sale = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).cancelSale(paymentId, 15700);
        } catch (CieloRequestException e) {
            // Em caso de erros de integração, podemos tratar o erro aqui.
            // os códigos de erro estão todos disponíveis no manual de integração.
            CieloError error = e.getError();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     Type mismatch: cannot convert from SaleResponse to Sale
>     Type mismatch: cannot convert from SaleResponse to Sale
>
> at cieloecommerce.sdk.ecommerce.Teste1.main(Teste1.java:49)

Baixei o sdk do site e importei como projeto Maven. Tentei realizar uma comprar de acordo com o manual porém recebi a mensagem acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria melhor se você postasse o código e não apenas uma imagem.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta: inserindo o código.

Comment: Você definiu `sale` como `Sale`, mas aparentemente o retorno de suas operações é um `SaleResponse`. Já viu na documentação para confirmar se está fazendo certo?

Comment: Provavelmente você tem que criar um objeto do tipo `SaleResponse` e armazenar nele o retorno das linhas `new CieloEcommerce(merchant...)`.

Comment: quando Utilizo SaleResponse perco o o metodo String paymentId = sale.getPayment().getPaymentId();

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a documentação é falha em nivel de desenvolvedor

Comment: @StatelessDev quando Utilizo SaleResponse perco  o metodo String paymentId = sale.getPayment().getPaymentId();

Comment: Bom, vai ser difícil alguém te ajudar. O erro é bastante claro, você não vai conseguir jogar o retorno do método nessa classe `Sale`. Resta a você dar uma lida na documentação, especialmente nesses métodos `captureSale()` e `cancelSale()` e verificar se é possível o retorno em alguma outra classe que tenha o método que você necessita.

Comment: Estou acompanhado o manual do github: https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/API-3.0-Java

Comment: Na documentação esta faltando uma variável, para solucionar o erro, deve-se criar a variável do tipo UpdateSaleResponse e com ela usar nos métodos em que esta acusando erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estou implementando este mesmo código no Android Studio.

Eu substituí `sale` por:

```
UpdateSaleResponse response = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).captureSale(paymentId, 15700, 0);
```

Acho que tanto `captureSale` quanto `cancelSale` é para utilizar em uma função separada da `createSale`. Como por exemplo:

```
private void RetrievePurchaseInfo() {
        try {
            UpdateSaleResponse response = new CieloEcommerce(merchant, Environment.SANDBOX).captureSale(paymentId, 15700, 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Response is "+response.getReturnCode());
            Log.i(TAG, "Provider return code is "+response.getProviderReturnCode());
            Log.i(TAG, "Provider return message is "+response.getProviderReturnMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CieloRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Enfim, comecei a implementar hoje pela primeira vez e ainda não conheço todas as funcionalidades.